# convert mmddyy to yyyymmdd in php?

Tags: php

I have a date i.e, **12-20-14(mm-dd-yy)** want to convert **2014-12-20(yyyy-mm-dd)**

I try

```
$date='12-20-14';
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));// Output :- 1970-01-01
```

Comment: [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 3):

The Simplest solution is

```
$date='12-20-14';
list($month, $date, $year) = explode('-',$date);
echo date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $date, $year));
```